# dialogflow success metadata

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

Is it possible to pass variables to the `Conversation success metadata` in dialogflow?  Specifically, I want to return current page and current flow, without having to type out its name.

Is there a way to pass variables into this JSON? (i.e. so that the "flow_name" and "page_name" fill automatically, based on the page that is open?

[image]

Comment: I dont think there is any documentation regarding passing data to conversation success metadata as this is only response signal for success conversation. It can possibly be done by a client library or a function if there is integration involved in the agent. https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment#success